# Two dynamically allocated blocks of memory overlap when I want to scale them up by using realloc() in C

Tags: memory-management, segmentation-fault, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

I allocated 2 blocks of memory pointed by the 2 pointers buyOrder and sellOrder in this struct

```
typedef struct orderBook {
int *buyOrder;
size_t buysize;
int *sellOrder;
size_t sellsize;
} *OrderBook;
```

The blocks were to record buy and sell orders, and I wanted to rescale them as needed on the go using realloc(), but I got Segmentation Fault when writing on and freeing the memory. When I checked the program using GDB, the memory appeared to overlap. Am I doing something wrong when allocating memory like that? What should I do if I want to have several blocks of memory that can be resized in C?

I implemented the buyOrder (array of int) as a heap, and reallocated the size of the block of memory when needed as follows (I did exactly the same thing for sellOrder):

```
/* insert new value */
void insertBuyOrder(OrderBook b, int item) {
    int last, I, J, temp, Flag;
    if (b->buyOrder[0] == 0) {
        b->buyOrder[0] = 1;
        b->buyOrder[1] = item;
    }
    else {
        last = b->buyOrder[0] + 1;
        if (last >= b->buysize - 1) {
            b->buyOrder = realloc(b->buyOrder, b->buysize * MULTIPLIER);
            assert(b->buyOrder);
            b->buysize = b->buysize * MULTIPLIER;
        }
        b->buyOrder[last] = item;
        b->buyOrder[0]++;
        I = last;
        Flag = 1;
        while (Flag) {
            J = (int) (I/2);
            if (J > 1) {
                /*find parent */
                if (b->buyOrder[J] < b->buyOrder[I]) {
                    temp = b->buyOrder[J];
                    b->buyOrder[J] = b->buyOrder[I];
                    b->buyOrder[I] = temp;
                    I = J;
                }
                else {
                    Flag = 0;
                }
            }
            else {
                Flag = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```